# Trying to import maven project but some dependencies are missing in eclipse after the import

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-plugin

I have tried everything but nothing worked for me.
Some of maven dependencies are missing in the eclipse but are present in the pom.xml file and local repository
Any help would be much appreciated

[Error Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ny8HE.png)

Comment: What does "everything" mean? Did you right-click on the project and tell Maven the update? Did you run a `mvn clean`?

Comment: Can you also post your `settings.xml` from maven installation directory? Probably an issue related to maven installation.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally When you run a Maven build, then Maven automatically downloads all the dependency jars into the local repository but I ran into the similar problem before and **updating the maven project did the trick for me** project>maven>update project

below I have explained whole thing from build to updating with screen shots hoping it helps you

1. right click project> run as> maven build[image]
2. above step should launch edit  configuration and launch window, here set Goals: clean install[image]
3. then click run
4. again right click on project>Maven>update project[image]
5. check force update of snapshot/releases and click ok[image]
6. finally, check under maven dependencies again if jars have downloaded

P.S. if you have JARs downloaded locally you can add them manually to your build path right click project>properties to resolve the issue [image]

Comment: Nothing worked out, i dont want to download each jar file from internet and put it into their local repository as it will take a hell lot of time.

Comment: Also i deleted the whole m2 repository and re-import the project again but still it didn't worked out. Aslo, i have installed apache maven in my laptop and change the embedded maven in eclipse but there are still multple errors

Comment: can you please share your pom file

Comment: Are you importing your maven project properly, make sure maven plugin is installed in your eclipse IDE, then follow these steps
Open Eclipse
Click File > Import
Type Maven in the search box under Select an import source:
Select Existing Maven Projects
Click Next
Click Browse and select the folder that is the root of the Maven project (probably contains the pom.xml file)
Click Next
Click Finish

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you correctly imported the project, the problem could be that you don't have the repositories defined that contain the dependencies you want to use.

See https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html for more information on how to define your repositories.